# Gaussian Mixture model log-likelihood to likelihood-Sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn, mixture-model, gmm, log-likelihood

I want to calculate the likelihoods instead of log-likelihoods. I know that score gives per sample average log-likelihood and for that I need to multiply score with sample size but the log likelihoods are very large negative numbers such as `-38567258.1157` and when I take `np.exp(scores)` , I get a zero. Any help is appreciated.

```
gmm=GaussianMixture(covariance_type="diag",n_components=2)
y_pred=gmm.fit_predict(X_test)
scores=gmm.score(X_test)
```

Comment: why do you want the likelihood and not the log likelihood ? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/289190/theoretical-motivation-for-using-log-likelihood-vs-likelihood if you have a lot of variables, it is likely that your average log likelihood is in this range

Comment: It was asked as a school work to calculate likelihoods instead of log-likelihoods